# Java - adding a method to a button in netbeans form

Tags: java, swing, oop

I have a `ShortestPath` class with a Dijkstra algorithm in it and a method called `computeRoutes`. I also have a form with a search button - I want to call the `computeRoutes` method from this button but can't figure out how to do this.

```
public class ShortestPath {
    public static void computeRoutes(Node source){

        source.minimumDistance = 0;
        PriorityQueue<Node> nodeQueue = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
        nodeQueue.add(source);

        while(!nodeQueue.isEmpty()){
            Node u = nodeQueue.poll();
            for(Edge e : u.neighbours){
                Node n = e.goal;
                int weight = e.weight;
                int distThruU = u.minimumDistance + weight;
                    if(distThruU < n.minimumDistance){
                        nodeQueue.remove(n);

                    n.minimumDistance = distThruU;
                    n.previousNode = u;
                    nodeQueue.add(n);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Node> getShortestRouteTo(Node goal){
        List<Node> route = new ArrayList<Node>();
        for(Node node = goal; node != null; node = node.previousNode)
            route.add(node);
        Collections.reverse(route);
        return route;
    }
}

public class BPForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
....
private void btnSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
(I want to call the computeRoutes method here)
```

Answer (score 3):

In netbeans designer double click this button. It will open code for ActionListener(If you don't know what this is. you should have a look at event handling for buttons) for this button. Just call computeRoutes() here using an Object(Have you already created an object?) of ShortestPath Class.

Answer (score 2):

i suppose you've implemented ActionListener, and in the code you have to overwrite

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if (e.getSource() == computeRoutes) {
       // put the logic here 
   }
.....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to implement OnClick Listener for button click event
and then just call your method

http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/awt/MouseClick.shtml

here is an example which will helps you

Comment: For a button, use an `ActionListener`.  That is typical of the rubbish advice people get from the RoseIndia site.